# How to understand "to" in "to die"?

Tags: grammar

I often come through the titles with "to die". And sometimes very confused about the meaning of this "to". Does that mean a future action? But definitely not in this context as the man already died before the news came out. Looking forward to your advice to help me understand this?

[image]

Comment: Non-finite verb; it may not refer to any tense.

Comment: _To die_ is the infinitive. It's normal to use the infinitive after (first, second... last) [noun], meaning that they are/were the first one who did that thing. "I was the first person in my family _to go_ to university."